# Php validation for multiple text fields with array name

Tags: php, arrays, validation, field

Hi I'm having a hard time making a validation for multiple fields with array name. I want to do php validation first not jquery or javascript.

My code for updating those multiple data in database if field is not empty is working fine.
Here's the update code I have for validation which I can't make it to work.

```
if (isset($_POST['savechange'])){

$name =$_POST ['name'];
$lastname =$_POST ['lastname'];
$email =$_POST ['email'];
$id = $_POST ['id'];
$pid = count(array_values ($id));

for($i=0;$i<($pid);$i++){

if (empty ($name[$i])) {
echo "Error: There is/are name field(s) that left empty";
}

}
}
```

This code is just echoing the the error * number of name fields that left empty. For example, if there are 3 fields that are empty the error is being echoed out 3 times.

if I do below codes, there's no error showing up even i change the name of field from name[$i] to name[] or vice versa on index page.
 I'm not sure what's wrong, please help!

```
if (empty ($name)) {
foreach($name as $x=>$x_value) {
echo "Field is empty for " . $x;
echo "<br>";
 }
 }
```

OR THIS

```
if (empty ($name)) {

echo "There is/are name field that left empty";
 }
```

I want just want display to display 1 error then the number of fields that are empty or not valid.

Comment: your original approach is fine. store the result in a boolean. after the loop, display.

Comment: Hi Karoly, thank you for your answer.. Can you please give me a code snippet on how to do that? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found solution on my problem, on link below.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

'Not valid' doesn't just mean empty. There are different reasons why a value is not valid. Therefore, validate each value one after another and count the amount of invalid values meanwhile. Eventually, after validating the complete data, you will be able to echo your errors alongside numeric data.